# Unable to use a working query in a SQL Server View: 'IS' not recognized '>' not recognized

Tags: sql-server, view

I have this query running if used directly as a string query:

```
SELECT BI.CUSTOMER_CODE AS [Customer Code],
       BI.ADD_NAME AS Customer,
       SI.ACCOUNT_CODE AS [Account Code],
       BID.BILL_NO AS [Bill #],
       BI.BILL_DATE AS [Bill Date],
       BI.CASHIER_NO AS [Cashier #],
       C.LOCATION,
       BID.SERVICE_CODE AS [Service Code],
       SI.NAME AS Service,
       BID.FEES AS [Service Fee],
       BID.REQUESTED_QTY AS [Requested Quantity],
       BID.REQUESTED_QTY * 10 AS [Knowledge Fee],
       BID.REQUESTED_QTY * 10 AS [Innovation Fee],
       BID.ITEM_TOT + BID.REQUESTED_QTY * 20 AS Total,
       BID.REQUESTED_QTY * BID.FEES AS [Total w/o Gov. Fee],
       IIF(BI.REMARKS IS NULL, '', IIF(LEN(BI.REMARKS) > 100, CONCAT(LEFT(BI.REMARKS, 100), '...'), BI.REMARKS)) AS [Remarks]
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO AS BI
    INNER JOIN dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL AS BID
        ON BI.BILL_NO = BID.BILL_NO
           AND BI.CASHIER_NO = BID.CASHIER_NO
           AND BI.PAY_MODE = BID.PAY_MODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.CASHIER AS C
        ON BI.CASHIER_NO = C.CASHIER_NO
    INNER JOIN dbo.SERVICE_INFO AS SI
        ON BID.SERVICE_CODE = SI.SERVICE_CODE
WHERE (BI.PAY_MODE = '3')
      AND (BI.INPUT_STATUS = '1')
      AND (MONTH(BI.BILL_DATE) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
      AND (YEAR(BI.BILL_DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE()))
      AND (BI.ACCOUNT_CODE IN ( 'ADP', 'ASP' ))
      AND (BID.SERVICE_CODE NOT IN ( 314, 1636, 1637, 1538 ))
ORDER BY [Customer Code],
         [Bill Date]
```

But once I try to use it in a view, I get these errors:

```
Error in list of function arguments: 'IS' not recognized.
Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

If I remove the last column with the IIF, everything works fine. Why is the query not accepted in a View?

Version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RC1) - 14.0.800.90 (X64)   Jul 11 2017 07:03:16   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview 10.0  (Build 16257: ) (Hypervisor)

Using SSMS to create a view using designer:

[image: View Designer, SSMS]

*EDIT*: Updated query to show the better JOINs as I posted in the wrong query but was using the better one

Comment: In that last line, what are you trying to do with: `IIF(BI.REMARKS....` ?

Comment: Ensuring it is printed as blank instead of NULL and it cannot exceed more than 100 characters other wise it'll mess the layout of the report on SSRS

Comment: @marc_s , I accidentally posted the wrong query. I have updated with the correct one and am still facing the same issue.

Comment: What SQL Server and what GUI do you use? Select @@version and post it here please

Comment: The fact is if you try to parse your query on SQL Server 2008, you'll get this error. IIF first appeared in SQL Server 2012, but 2008 does not give you the error 'iif' is not a recognized built-in function name, but it gives you exactly what you've got: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.

Comment: @sepupic, Update question

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. How can I update your question? Did you mean YOU updated your question? I still cannot see your server version

Comment: @sepupic, check now

Comment: I think it's just a GUI bug. Copy your view text in a query window, get rid of top 100 and order by, and try to execute it

Comment: Query is executing perfectly. It just won't accept when i paste it in as SQL for the view

Comment: You didn't understand me. To create a view you DON'T need GUI, you can do it just adding CREATE VIEW dbo.my_view as ... before your query

Comment: @sepupic, you are right: If I create using a query, it works.

Answer (score 1):

With @sepupic's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779563/unable-to-use-a-working-query-in-a-sql-server-view-is-not-recognized-not?noredirect=1#comment78519171_45779563) help, I was finally able to create the view through query instead of the designer. This view cannot be designed anymore as the error is still there but I'm able to call this view and get data and that is a success for me.