# Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized. Unable to parse query text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like below in sql server, when i use it in the new query window it has no syntax error and it is executed but when i use it in a view and right click on it for changing design, it has below syntax error but any way it is executed and shows records.

```
 Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
 Unable to parse query text.
```

---

```
SELECT tblDocuments.[Project No],
       tblDocuments.Originator,
       tblDocuments.Zone,
       tblDocuments.Unit,
       tblDocuments.Discipline,
       tblDiscipline.DiscDesc,
       tblDocuments.[Document Type],
       tblDocuments.[Owner Document Number],
       tblDocuments.[Sazeh Document Number],
       tblDocuments.[IDENTIFICATION CODE1],
       tblDocuments.[IDENTIFICATION CODE2],
       tblDocuments.[Document Title],
       tblDocuments.SheetNumber,
       CHARINDEX('(', [tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number]) - 1 AS Doc_Visual_pos,
       IIF(CHARINDEX('(', [tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number]) - 1 > 0, LEFT([tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number], CHARINDEX('(', [tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number]) - 1), [tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number]) AS Doc_Visual,
       tblTransmittals.REV,
       tblTransmittals.POI,
       tblPurposeofIssue.[Purpose of Issue Description],
       tblTransmittals.CC,
       tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-NO],
       tblTransmittals.[To-Owner-Tr-No],
       tblTransmittals.[MC-CSheet-No],
       tblTransmittals.AcCode,
       tblTransmittals.Pages,
       tblTransmittals.PaperSize,
       tblTransmittals.SJC_TO_MC_Let_NO,
       tblTransmittals.MC_TO_SJC_Let_No,
       tblTransmittals.To_FEng_Tr_No,
       tblTransmittals.SJC_Tr_No,
       tblTransmittals.Ext_Int,
       tblTransmittals.[Early Planned Issue Date],
       tblTransmittals.[Late Planned Issue Date],
       tblTransmittals.[Tag-No],
       tblTransmittals.Phase,
       tblTransmittals.SubPhase,
       tblTransmittals.ActivityID,
       tblTransmittals.Manhour,
       tblTransmittals.WorkPackage,
       tblTransmittals.[DCN-No],
       tblTransmittals.[DCR-No],
       tblTransmittals.[DCR-Reason],
       tblTransmittals.Remark,
       tblTransmittals.LastRevPerDoc,
       tblTransmittals.LastRevPerPOI,
       tblTransmittals.HoldBy,
       tblTransmittals.CommentID,
       tblTransmittals.ExTrID,
       tblTransmittals.HT_TR_No,
       tblTransmittals.Recipients,
       tblTransmittals.MC_HD_Comment_No,
       tblTransmittals.[CT- Transmittals],
       tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo.[CT_CS_Tr-Date],
       tblTransmittals.DefaultForDocument,
       tblTransmittals.HyperDoc,
       tblTransmittals.root
FROM tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo
     RIGHT JOIN(((tblDocuments
                  LEFT JOIN tblTransmittals ON tblDocuments.[Owner Document Number] = tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number])
                 LEFT JOIN tblPurposeofIssue ON tblTransmittals.POI = tblPurposeofIssue.[Purpose of Issue])
                LEFT JOIN tblDiscipline ON tblDocuments.Discipline = tblDiscipline.DiscCode)ON tb_CT_CS_transmittalNo.CT_CS_Tr_No = tblTransmittals.[CT- Transmittals]
WHERE tblTransmittals.Remark_Doc <> 'Deleted'
   OR tblTransmittals.Remark_Doc IS NULL;
```

i would like this does not show this syntax error when i want to change design of view.

Comment: Personally, I suggest not using the designer; they're not great. If you want to make changes, do so using T-SQL.

Comment: On a different note, I strongly suggest using aliases and good use of whitespace. it'll make your SQL far more readable and bloated. Also, are those columns with carriage returns in their names?! You need to fix those!!! (For example, you column `[Early Planned Issue Date],` has a carriage returns before `Planned`). Any kind of special character in a column named is frowned upon (including a whitespace like you have), but a carriage return is a huge no-no.

Comment: I've reformatted your query for you, which highlights the columns with carriage returns in their names quite easily.

Comment: thanks, when i copied and pasted from sql-server to  site, it found carriage, in sql-server editor does not have carriage return

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use a working query in a SQL Server View: 'IS' not recognized '>' not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779563/unable-to-use-a-working-query-in-a-sql-server-view-is-not-recognized-not)